# Synchronized methods on different objects,different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my bank class that has deposit and withdraw methods that are synchronized.

```
public class BankAccount {

private float blance;

public synchronized void deposit(float amount) {
    blance += amount;
}

public synchronized void withdraw(float amount) {
    blance -= amount;
  }
}
```

Which of this is true:

1: In several object of this class, `deposite()` method can run with `withdraw()` method in the same time .

2: In one instance (object) of this class, `deposite()` method can run with own itself my two threads in the same time.(and consider this for `withraw()` by itself method).

Is `synchronized` for prevent running methods in the same time in several objects or in several threads?

Comment: This is homework , please study some more

Comment: @Adel No this not homework for me, i am java learner.

Comment: @user3314119 Seems unlikely considering you made your account today... Presumably just to ask this question. Read more about synchronization, it isn't a foreign topic. You will find lots of info about it.

Comment: @JoshM can you give me a link to find my answer?

Comment: You won't find a concrete answer to your question. You must read about synchronization and apply that knowledge to answer your question.

Comment: The CoP videos may be of help - https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading/#/lecture/108950

Comment: And don't use float to represent monetary amounts...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like homework and shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a non static method as `synchronized` means the code will be synchronized on the object instance itself. In effet, writing:

```
public synchronized void doStuff()
{
    whatever();
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public void doStuff()
{
    synchronized(this) {
        whatever();
    }
}
```

Google for "Java Concurrency in Practice". And buy the book.

Comment: Thanks for respond, What about for `synchronized static methods`?

Comment: Then it will synchronize on the class object itself: `synchronized(MyClass.class) { whatever(); }`. This works, since all `Class` objects are singletons.